# jquery, graphing recommendations based on selective conditions

Tags: jquery

I am looking for something that can do the following:

-can do log scales axes graphing
-have the ability to download the points on the graph into csv/excel
-looks great visually
-possible to do 10-20 plots on graph
-create smooth curves if given a set of dots

Are there any items on the web that would perform in what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, i just ended up building gnuplot server side and add the features myself

Answer (score 0):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) or [Raphael Graphing](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) or perhaps you may have to write your own by hacking one of these to get the functionality you want, especially with the logarithmic scale requirement.